# psuedo class selectors in CSS using a specific id

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I get the following CSS to apply to only a specific class as oppose to all links on my page

```
a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 149px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4.7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: The FabioG's proposed answer should work in the general case, perhaps there is something else causing the issue. Can you post a sample of your HTML? Are there any other CSS rules styling `a`s?

Answer (score 2):

add your class in the css if it's a class you're referening to

```
a.MyClass:link, a.MyClass:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 149px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4.7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

or the id

```
 a#MyId:link, a#MyId:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 149px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #98bf21;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4.7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

Comment: It's a set of links that are styled as like a vertical menu, I have tried naming it both a class and an id - and then changing the CSS, as soon as I do, all the CSS code seems to become invalid

Comment: can you had an example of the html in your question?